# How identify bounded Borel measurable functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $S$ be a topological semigroup, and $M(S)$ be bounded, regular complex Borel measures on $S$. How can we identify bounded Borel measurable functions with elements in $M^*(S)$?

Comment: Do you mean $\langle f,\mu\rangle := \int_S f(x)\mu(\mathrm dx)$ for any $\mu \in M(S)$ and bounded Borel $f$?


Answer (score 1):

Please consult pages 39-40 and Propositions 4.13 and 4.14 of

> H.G. Dales, A.T.-M. Lau and D. Strauss, Second duals of measure algebras, *Dissertationes Mathematicae* (*Rozprawy Matematyczne*), **481**, 2012, p. 1-121. (available also [here](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmt6hgd/preprints/Dissertatmeasurealgebrafinal.pdf))

for a description of an embedding of the commutative C*-algebra of bounded Borel functions on $K$ into $C(\tilde{K})=C(K)^{**}$ which might be of interest to you.